# A squigly symbol

Tags: symbols

How do you make that symbol in between the `L` and the `K`. This symbol comes from the Dummit and Foote Abstract Algebra book 5.5 exercises
[image]

Comment: I suggest `$L \wr K$` and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/47927

Comment: Can't you just rote a tilde by -90°? `\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\~}` (part of the `graphicx` package.) ETA: Not being a mathematician, I didn't recognize `\wr` :-)

Answer (score 4):

http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

yielded the command `\wr` mathmode

Comment: Jasper was 13secs faster ;)